Is there any concept of three shivas in shaivism similar to three vishnus of vaishnavism
In Vaishnavism, there is a concept of three vishnus. Mahāvishnu, Garbhodakaśāyī Vishnu and Ksirodakaśāyī Vishnu (Paramātmā).
Is there any parallel concept in shaivism?

Your question In Vaishnavism, there is a concept of three vishnus. Mahāvishnu, Garbhodakaśāyī Vishnu and Ksirodakaśāyī Vishnu (Paramātmā).Is there any parallel concept in shaivism?
In Shaivism, Bhagavān Shiva has been described in the names of His five faces i.e. different facets of Lord Shiva also known as the five incarnations of the supreme Brahman. Nandīśvara in Shiva purana [Section-3 (Śatarudra-saṃhitā) Chapter-1]) says each of these faces viz., (1) Īsana (ईशान), (2) Tatpurusha (तत्पुरुष), (3) Aghora (अघोर), (4) Vāmadeva (वामदेव) and (5) Sadyojāta (सद्योजाता), are assigned with Purusha(Self) and Prakriti(Nature) and evloutes (of Prakriti) which are Buddhi(Intellect), Ahamkāra(I-am-ness), and Manas(Mind) as follows[slokas: 39-43]:
ईशानः पुरुषो घोरो वामसंज्ञस्तथैव च ।।
ब्रह्मसंज्ञो महेशस्य मूर्तयः पंच विश्रुताः ।। ३९।।
īśānaḥ puruṣo ghoro vāmasaṃjñastathaiva ca ||
brahmasaṃjño maheśasya mūrtayaḥ paṃca viśrutāḥ ||39||

The five famous forms of Maheśa are thus named Īśāna, Puruṣa, Aghora, Vāma and Brahman.||39||

ईशानः शिवरूपश्च गरीयान्प्रथमः स्मृतः ।।
भोक्तारं प्रकृतेः साक्षात्क्षेत्रज्ञमधितिष्ठति ।। ४०।।
īśānaḥ śivarūpaśca garīyānprathamaḥ smṛtaḥ ||
bhoktāraṃ prakṛteḥ sākṣātkṣetrajñamadhitiṣṭhati || 40||

Īśāna form of Śiva is the first and the principal one. It directly 
occupies and presides over the individual soul, the enjoyer of Prakṛti.।। 40।।

शैवस्तत्पुरुषाख्यश्च स्वरूपो हि द्वितीयकः ।।
गुणाश्रयात्मकं भोग्यं सर्वज्ञमधितिष्ठति ।। ४१।।
śaivastatpuruṣākhyaśca svarūpo hi dvitīyakaḥ ||
guṇāśrayātmakaṃ bhogyaṃ sarvajñamadhitiṣṭhati || 41||

Tatpuruṣa form of Śiva is the second. It occupies and presides over every 
object of enjoyment, the support of the attributes.|| 41||

धर्माय स्वांगसंयुक्तं बुद्धितत्त्वं पिनाकिनः ।।
अघोराख्यस्वरूपो यस्तिष्ठत्यंतस्तृतीयकः ।। ४२।।
dharmāya svāṃgasaṃyuktaṃ buddhitattvaṃ pinākinaḥ ||
aghorākhyasvarūpo yastiṣṭhatyaṃtastṛtīyakaḥ || 42||

The third form of Śiva is Aghora that stands within, occupies.and presides over  
the principle of intelligence with all its ramifications for the sake of Dharma.|| 42||

वामदेवाह्वयो रूपश्चतुर्थः शङ्करस्य हि ।। 
अहंकृतेरधिष्ठानो बहुकार्यकरः सदा ।।  ४३ ।।
vāmadevāhvayo rūpaścaturthaḥ śaṅkarasya hi ||
ahaṃkṛteradhiṣṭhāno bahukāryakaraḥ sadā ||  43 ||

The fourth form of Śiva is Vāmadeva who presides over the ego[Ahamkāra] and is many
incessant activities.||  43 ||

The 20 principle evolutes, which are Jnānedriya(ears,skin,eyes,tongue and nose),  Karmendriya(mouth,hands,feet,genitals and bowels), Tan-matras/Senses(sound,touch,form,taste and smell) and panca-bootha (space,air,fire,water and earth), governed by the five facets of Bhagavan Maheshvara are given below [slokas: 44-48]:
ईशानाह्वस्वरूपो हि शंकरस्येश्वरः सदा ।। 
श्रोत्रस्य वचसश्चापि विभोर्व्योम्नस्तथैव च ।।  ४४ ।।
īśānāhvasvarūpo hi śaṃkarasyeśvaraḥ sadā || 
śrotrasya vacasaścāpi vibhorvyomnastathaiva ca ||  44 ||

The Īśāna form of Śiva is the permanent lord of the organ of hearing, speech and 
the all-pervading sky.||  44 ||

त्वक्पाणिस्पर्शवायूनामीश्वरं रूपमैश्वरम् ।। 
पुरुषाख्यं विचारज्ञा मतिमन्तः प्रचक्षते ।।  ४५ ।।
tvakpāṇisparśavāyūnāmīśvaraṃ rūpamaiśvaram || 
puruṣākhyaṃ vicārajñā matimantaḥ pracakṣate || 45 ||

Intelligent and wise persons call Tatpuruṣa as the lord of Tvac (organ of touch perception),
hand, sense of touch and the wind element.|| 45 ||

वपुषश्च रसस्यापि रूपस्याग्नेस्तथैव च ।। 
अघोराख्यमधिष्ठानं रूपमाहुर्मनीषिणः ।। ४६।
vapuṣaśca rasasyāpi rūpasyāgnestathaiva ca || 
aghorākhyamadhiṣṭhānaṃ rūpamāhurmanīṣiṇaḥ || 46||

Intelligent persons call the form Aghora, the support of the physical the body, 
sense of taste, of colour and of fire as well.|| 46||

रशनायाश्च पायोश्च रसस्यापां तथैव च ।। 
ईश्वरं वामदेवाख्यं स्वरूपं शांकरं स्मृतम् ।। ४७।।
raśanāyāśca pāyośca rasasyāpāṃ tathaiva ca || 
īśvaraṃ vāmadevākhyaṃ svarūpaṃ śāṃkaraṃ smṛtam || 47||

Vāmadeva form of Śiva is remembered as the lord of the organ of taste, 
of the organ of excretion, of taste itself and of waters as well.|| 47||

प्राणस्य चैवोपस्थस्य गंधस्य च भुवस्तथा ।। 
सद्योजाताह्वयं रूपमीश्वरं शांकरं विदुः ।। ४८।।
prāṇasya caivopasthasya gaṃdhasya ca bhuvastathā || 
sadyojātāhvayaṃ rūpamīśvaraṃ śāṃkaraṃ viduḥ || 48||

They know the form of Sadyojāta as the lord of the organ of smell, of smell itself, 
of the earth and of the generative organ.|| 48||

It must be noted that Lord Shiva is said to be the supreme lord for these following five functions (पंच-कृत्य/Pancha-Kritya) according to Shaiva-Siddhanta (शैवसिद्धान्त/சைவ சித்தாந்தம்):

Creation (Srishti/सृष्टि): Īsana(ईशान) creates all the worlds and beings.
Preservation (Sthithi/स्थिति): Vāmadeva(वामदेव) is responsible for the continuation of all the worlds and beings. He is the sustaining power of breath (Prāneswara) and the digestive power of fire (Jatharāgni).
Destruction (Laya-लय/Samhāra-संहार): Aghora(अघोर) is the one who is responsible for death and destruction. But with this aspect, he is also responsible for the renewal of life and rebirth (punarjanma).
Concealment (Tirobhāva/तिरोभाव): Tatpurusha(तत्पुरुष), is the one who casts the net of delusion or māyā, upon the whole creation. He does it so that the order and regularity of the worlds are not disrupted.
Revelation (Anugraha/अनुग्रह): Sadyojāta(सद्योजाता) is the master of liberation. No one can achieve liberation without his grace and blessings.

Good Luck!
